# Windows 10 equivalent to OSX's ⌘+D to navigate to my desktop, ⌘+Shift+H for Home, ⌘+shift+A for apps etc

Tags: windows-10, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, cross-platform

In finder on OSX there are shortcuts to special folders like the user's Desktop, the user's Home directory and the Applications directory (from memory it's <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> for ~/Desktop, <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> for ~/ and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> for /Applications, but it's been a while since I moved to the dark side, so please feel free to edit).

One thing that's always bugged me is that there is no equivalent for Windows. To navigate to my home folder is particularly annoying, I have to go **My PC>C:>Users>stib>** which is way too many clicks. So is there an addon or hack that mimics the OSX behaviour? Ideally it would work in open file dialogs as well as in Explorer.

**EDIT**
Here's what I tried with AutoHotKey

```
;-- ctrl win d opens the documents dir
^#d::
send {Ctrl down}l{Ctrl up}
send Documents{Enter}
Return
```

That works in some dialogs, but not all. For example the dialog that opens with notepad++ looks like this,

[image]

and neither the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> nor <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> shortcuts would move focus to the address box. So that script would send the word "Documents" to the name box, resulting in it creating or opening a file called Documents in whatever folder it happened to be open in. The workaround is to send the absolute path to the Documents folder, but it's still a bit brittle. If focus is moved away from the dialog for any reason (eg a notification window from another ap opening) the script will send keystrokes to random elements. Not optimal.

Comment: Ctrl+L -> "stib" ;)

Comment: This is easily answered using google. What did your research show?

Comment: There does not seem to be any equivalent that I can find. Besides, searching for windows desktop shortcut just produces endless pages telling me how to press windows D. Yeah, I know.

Answer (score 2):

I just started researching this topic. If you don't mind some barbarian solutions:

1. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd> at least 2 times, depending on where your initial path is.
   (If you keep the UP arrow key pressed for a couple of seconds, you will reach the Desktop regardless of where you are). Then press ENTER to actually save the file.
2. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) to focus the address bar.
   From here you can:

- type out "Desktop" and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, followed by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- type "de" and press <kbd>DOWN</kbd> to select Desktop from the autocomplete list, then <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to get a list of recent locations, which most likely includes the desktop (you will still have to navigate using the arrow keys),  and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

3. Assuming you have Desktop pinned to your Quick access and is the first item, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> (or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>) 3 times, followed by <kbd>HOME</kbd>, <kbd>DOWN</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (if Desktop is not the first item, use the arrow keys to navigate to where it is), <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

- Notepad++ seems to use the old type of Save as dialogue (Win 7 style I think). In this case, #1 and #2 won't work. (#1 does get you to the desktop, but all other keys seem to die after that). However #3 works, but the sequence in this case is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> x3, <kbd>DOWN</kbd>, <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The structure of file system one Windows is different from the Mac, so sometimes there is no strict equivalent.

You can use the shortcut <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to minimize all open windows and see the desktop. Use it again to restore those open windows.

In **File Explorer**, **This PC** is technically your home folder. For example, let's say you have a folder named Test on the **Desktop**. If you go to **This PC** > **Desktop** > **Test**, now check the address bar and you will see **C:\Users\stib\Desktop\Test**. In **Folder Options**, you can change what **File Explorer** opens to. You can choose **This PC**, or **Quick access**.

But more accurately, your home folder is actually your name in **File Explorer** and it is displayed at the same level along with **Quick access** and **This PC**.

You can customize **Quick access** and add all the folders that you use more often. This way you can reach them much faster. Right-click on any folder and select **Pin to Quick access**. Those folders not only show up in **File Explorer** in **Quick access**, but also when you have a **File Explorer** window open and right-click on its button in the **Task Bar**, those folders show up pinned to the context menu and clicking on one of them opens a new **File Explorer** window to that folder.

Comment: I'm specifically looking for keyboard shortcuts. I realise I can see the desktop with Win+D but that doesn't help when I'm in a choose-folder dialogue.

Comment: No, that doesn't help in the dialog, but the **Quick access** does. Try it. It always comes at the top of the folders list on the left side. You can easily create new hotkeys in Windows, but I don't recommend it. If you really want to do it, I can tell you how, or you can simply google it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to avoid mousing when I can. I already use autohotkeys to automate other things, I was hoping for a less kludgy solution.